# The remote server returned an error: NotFound #2

Tags: c#, wcf, silverlight

I have written a very simple WCF service, that worked fine (code below), then I added a bunch of further methods (which are exatly the same, apart from the reference different tables).  However for some reason, I get the error "The remote server returned an error: NotFound." when I try and call the new methods (I have refreshed the service reference)

**Service Reference Interface**

```
[OperationContract]
TempSchool[] GetSchools();
```

**Service Reference Method**

```
 public TempSchool[] GetSchools()
 {
     return _db.TempSchools.ToArray();
 }
```

**Calling code**

```
_proxy.GetSchoolsCompleted += new EventHandler<GetSchoolsCompletedEventArgs>(_proxy_GetSchoolsCompleted);
_proxy.GetSchoolsAsync();
```

**generated code where error occurs**

```
public System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<SilverlightTTAS6.TacticalServiceReference.ModelAction> EndGetModelActions(System.IAsyncResult result) 
{
   object[] _args = new object[0];
   **System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<SilverlightTTAS6.TacticalServiceReference.ModelAction> _result = ((System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<SilverlightTTAS6.TacticalServiceReference.ModelAction>)(base.EndInvoke("GetModelActions", _args, result)));**
   return _result;
}
```

So I guess there is some configuration code that is not being generated somewhere... any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Associations!

My first table had no associations, but the others do, and those associations are causing the errors.

However, it does not seem to be the order in which the tables are loaded (data-integrity), any table with an association gets this error, even if it is the top of the hierarchy.